# Sort collection by relationship value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested

I want to sort a laravel collection by an attribute of an nested relationship.

So I query all projects (only where the project has tasks related to the current user), and then I want to sort the projects by deadline date of the task relationship.

Current code:

Project.php

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProjectTask');
}
```

Task.php

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project');
}
```

UserController

```
$projects = Project->whereHas('tasks', function($query){
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })->get()->sortBy(function($project){
        return $project->tasks()->orderby('deadline')->first(); 
    });
```

I don't know if im even in the right direction?
Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use something like [`join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) and then sort by whatever you need.

For exapmle:

```
Project::join('tasks', 'tasks.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->select('projects.*', DB::raw("MAX(tasks.deadline) as deadline_date"))
        ->groupBy('tasks.project_id')
        ->orderBy('deadline_date')
        ->get()
```

**Update**

```
Project::join('tasks', function ($join) {
            $join->on('tasks.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
                ->where('tasks.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->whereNull('tasks.completed');
        })
        ->select('projects.*', DB::raw("MAX(tasks.deadline) as deadline_date"))
        ->groupBy('tasks.project_id')
        ->orderBy('deadline_date')
        ->get()
```

**Update2**

Add `with` in your query as:

```
->with(['tasks' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
       ->whereNull('completed');
})
```

Comment: I think this will be best solution for now, but there is one tricky part (for me), I want to sort by deadline of tasks, but only tasks where *completed* column is null.. I tried adding whereNull('tasks.completed') but that doens't affect the order. Can you elevate on this please?

Comment: Perfect, the order is correct now, but I'm still missing my projects in the array of projects now, can you just help me with attaching all the task where user_id on the joined tasks table is a specific user (authenticated user), you can see I used whereHas for this in mij OP pretty please?

Comment: Just add one more `where` in your `join` closure, check the updated answer.

Comment: Ye I allready added that one myself, but this still returns an array of flat projects, whereas I would like to include the tasks inside each project object..

Comment: If you want to load the relation then `with` is your friend, check the updated answer.

Comment: Omg I tried that before and it was not working, now it does, thank you very much, I've picked up a few things on this journey :)
Btw best is to just put the `with` just before the `->get()`?

Comment: Although it's not required put the `with` just before the `->get()` but for readability, you should follow this.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: One more thing tho, thanks again for the major help so far, but I have a parent_id column on the tasks table, where I can nest tasks to child tasks (only 1 level deep tho). Now I have a nice list of projects and within that list i have all tasks.. Is there a way to have the list like this : project -> parent_task -> child_tasks? There are only 3 levels total so this should be that hard I think? Thanks anyways bro!

Comment: It's little complicated, I would suggest you ask an another question as it will be helpful for the future user.

Answer (score 12):

A nice clean way of doing this is with the `.` operator

```
$projects = Project::all()->load('tasks')->sortBy('tasks.deadline');
```

Comment: I've also tried this approach but I only want to get the projects *whereHas* tasks assigned to me, so I have to use whereHas and I can't get it to work with load.. If you have more input please let me know thnx

Comment: So load() is not eager loading? It's like doing a "JOIN"?

Comment: Hi @Mtxz, you are correct `load()` is eager loading. Laravel is not necessarily doing an explicit `JOIN` but rather a series of queries constrained by the relationships you have assigned each model. I would recommend watching the results of your eager loading using Barry Heuvel's Debug bar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) as this will give you more of an appreciation of what is happening than my explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
$tasks = Task::with('project')
            ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->orderBy('deadline')
            ->get();
```

After that you can access project properties like below

```
$tasks->first()->project()->xxx
```

Comment: I've tried some stuff out, but I want the tasks to be grouped by project.. I tried groupby but for some reason I lose results of my collection.. I'm gonna try the join option for now, maybe I try some more later..