# Sort collection by numbers and then by null numbers using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collect

I have a collection in which I need to order by totals (from lowest to highest) and in case a client does not have a total (-), leave it below the clients that do.

The collection returns the following:

[image]

And my intention is to achieve the next result (first customers with total and then customers who do not have a total):

[image]

```
$sales = Sale::with('client')
         ->get()
         ->map(function($sale){
              $sale['total'] = $sale->total ? $sale->total * $sale->quantity : '--';
              return $sale;
         });
```

I tried using `sortBy('total')` but it does not work for me.

**Solution:**

```
    $sales = Sale::with('client')
         ->get()
         ->map(function($sale){
              $sale['total'] = $sale->total ? $sale->total * $sale->quantity : '--';
              return $sale;
         })
         ->sort(function($a, $b) {
            if ($a->total == "--" && $b->total != "--") {
                return 1;
            }
            if ($a->total != "--" && $b->total == "--") {
                return -1;
            }
            if ($a->total == "--" && $b->total == "--") {
                return 0;
            }
            return $a->total - $b->total;
        });
```

Thanks for the help. Regards

Comment: orderByRaw('-total DESC') try this one

Comment: The "total" field I create using "map" within the collection, therefore I can not use orderBy. Thanks.

Comment: can you please show us how your table (what fields) `sales` and table `clients` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to order by asc on eagerload :

```
$sales = Sale::select('total', 'client_id')
             ->with(['client'=>function($query){
                $query->orderBy('total', 'ASC');
            }])
        ->get();
```

edited:

```
$sales = Sale::select('total', 'client_id') 
               ->with('client')
               ->orderBy('total', 'ASC')
               ->get();
```

Comment: Field "total" belongs to the "Sales" table, not "Clients". Thanks

Comment: It does not help to apply "orderB"y, since the "total" field is obtained within the collection using "map". I must apply the order criterion to the collection using "sortBy" or "sort". Thanks

Comment: @CristianMeza add the whole query and modification with map then.

Comment: the nested orderBy will only orderBy the Clients from each Sale. Not the Sales themselves.

Comment: @Leorent Edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a SQL "join" if you want to orderBy a relationship, as with() will eager load result after (you can still use the with() if you need the eager loading of clients).

**Use a JOIN**

```
Sale::select('total', 'client_id')->join( 'client', 'client.sale_id', '=', 'sale.id' )>orderBy( 'client.total', 'ASC' )->get();
```

Not sure about the foreign names and stuff, but you get the idea.

**Use a sort** (on your collection)

```
$data->sortBy('client.total');
```

You should prefer solution 1 (JOIN) as second solution need database query + collection processing.

Edit: you can do more complex join statement

Edit2: check [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189785/sort-collection-by-relationship-value)

Comment: I can not use join, since the "total" field I get in the collection using "map". I must apply the order if or if to the collection. Thanks.

Comment: ahh yes I see. So true, you'll need to sort the collection, after mapping.