# OrderBy with 'relationship' in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am having following tables,

- User (id, name)
- category (id, category_name, order)
- user_category (id, user_id, category_id)
- specialties (id, spe_name)
- user_specialities (id, spe_id, user_id)

I am trying to get all the users with all related specialties order by 'order' in a category where each user has under category in table 'user_category'.

I have tried with relationship 'with' but I am not able to orderby on this query.

Any thoughts where I may wrong?

Comment: can you post your query?

Comment: $query = Coach::with(['specialities','specialities.speciality','coachUnderCategories', 'coachUnderCategories.coachCategory'])
            ->orderBy('coach_categories.order', 'desc');

Comment: Yes, I tried this way as well but data "with"specialties relationship is always null.

Comment: there is no coach_categories model function which you with, follow the below ans which i give then works.

Comment: In your answer, 'supplier.id' what is supplier? is it a table name or relationship property?

Comment: I am trying to get all users having all specialties order by user category id.

Answer (score 0):

`With()` makes multiple queries using sql operator whereIn I think, therefore you don't have the field available when you're trying to orderBy on it.

There are two ways you can go about this,

either you `join()` the tables together and then `orderBy` on the joined field, or you sort the collection the query results in like this

```
$sortedResult = SomeModel::with('all your relations')->get()
    ->sortByDesc(function ($anItem) {
        return $anItem->category->order;
    })->all();
```

If you wanna go with the join, here's another post: [Sort collection by relationship value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189785/sort-collection-by-relationship-value)

---

**Edit according to comment**

```
User::join('user_category', 'user_category.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->join('user_specialities', 'user_specialities.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->select('user.*')
    ->selectRaw('(select group_concat(spe_name) from specialities where specialities.id = user_specialiliteies.spe_id) as specialities')
    ->orderBy('user_category.order')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Also, if you join the tables, you won't get the ['model' => 'relation' => []] structure, just a flat ['allAttributes' => 'andValues', ...]

Comment: I have tried this before, it works but not with pagination.

Comment: And when I am trying to join the table, I can able to fetch the data orderby but can not get the multiple specialties in a single row by like 'group_concat'.

Comment: Yeah, fetching all and sorting after makes for poor optimization. I think the query in the edit part of the answer works but it's not that pretty, hope it helps and if you find a better way please let me know! At least it should take care of both orderBy and group_concat.